# custom css not working in my inherited child theme

Tags: magento2, customize, ultimo

I am using ultimo theme for my store. Problem is in its `_custom.less` file there is written to make a new child theme for customizing the css. I have made the new theme but the problem is I am not able to customize it any way.All the theme is inherited successfully but when I changed the css it is not changing . What am I missing ?
This is my child theme directory.

```
app>design>frontend>Vendor>Child_theme_name>web>css>source>_theme.less
```

Comment: Magento 1 or 2 ? you should put just one version because it's not the same

Answer (score 0):

Place the child theme at following location

> app->frontend->childtheme

Run commands at root of magento:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: it is already there. let me add the full path

Comment: parent theme and child theme will be separate folders.

Comment: yeah they are in the separate folder but nothing changed. also i have run the command. For the testing i am using body{ background-color: #ff0000; }

Comment: i think currently your are using child-theme folder into parent-theme.

Comment: are you working on server or localhost. if you working on live server give me access i will fix it

Comment: parent theme is `app>design>frontend>Infortis>ultimo`

Comment: can you send me child path please? I know default ultimo child place at app>design>frontend>Infortis>ultimo-child

Comment: `app>design>frontend>Vendor>Child_theme_name>web>css>source>_theme.less`

Comment: sorry that was typo error in my question let me edit this.

Comment: did you get my comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65434/discussion-between-paarth-and-tech-geek).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue follow these steps see below:

Step 1- Go to root using putty and check mode

-To display the current mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

if mode is not developer mode then change mode

magento deploy:mode:set developer

Step 2- Change mode in admin section. client mode should select to reflect on frontend CSS. for doing this goto admin

Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Frontend Development Workflow then select "Client side less compilation"

Step 3- Disable cache and clear cache

-View the cache status

```
php bin/magento cache:status
```

-Enable or disable cache types

```
php bin/magento cache:enable

php bin/magento cache:disable
```

-Clean and flush cache types

php `bin/magento` cache:clean

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Step 4- run these command to remove the file from var and pub/static-content

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Step 5- finally run the deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```